# ASP.NET C# <asp:Button type="button"> but still acting like <asp:Button type="submit">

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="LoginBtn" type="Button" Text="Login" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('jsLogin').style.display='inline-grid'" />
```

As the title states, the above line of code is what is present in my Master.master page.

But when I run the debugger (visual studio 2017), chrome and the application run the button with a postback, and when I examine the element, it's still showing

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$LoginBtn" value="Login" onclick="document.getElementById('jsLogin').style.display='inline-grid';" id="LoginBtn">
```

I have *zero* clue what to do.

*UPDATE 7/19/2018 (20 minutes later)*

reverted to an older source control:

the only change was near the top of the master.master:

```
<html lang="en-us">
    <form runat="server">
        <head runat="server">
            <asp:scriptmanager runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
```

instead of

```
<html lang="en-us">
    <head runat="server">
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:scriptmanager runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
```

and on the Default.aspx page this line:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master.master" %>
```

is not commented out.

Literally nothing else changed O.o  Someone who knows more about ASP.Net than me please clue me in.

*Update 7/20/2018 - 18:39 gmt*

Reproduced the root cause.

```
<asp:textbox>
```

was set to *required*.  I removed the *required* and created a custom javascript function.  Apparently there is a problem with FormsAuthentication.Signout() when you try to clear authentication on hidden forms that have *required* set.

```
<script>
    function validation() {
        var username = document.getElementById('uNameLogin').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('uPasswordLogin').value;
        if (username == null || password == null || username == "" || password == "") 
        {
            document.getElementById('uNameLogin').value = "User Name & Password Required!";
            return false;
        }
     }
</script>
```

after adding that, to prevent the post back I followed the suggestion of adding *return false* to the OnClientClick javascript:

```
OnClientClick="javascript:document.getElementById('jsLogin').style.display='inline-grid'; return false;"
```

and it resolved the problem of the Login button causing postback.

Comment: If, while the debugger is running, I go in and _manually_ change the type="submit" to type="button" it will run correctly.

Comment: Try setting [UseSubmitBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't stop the button from _doPostBack

It does change the inspect element to be the following:

<input type="button" name="ctl00$LoginBtn" value="Login" onclick="document.getElementById('jsLogin').style.display='inline-grid';__doPostBack('ctl00$LoginBtn','')" id="LoginBtn">

Comment: It should.. Anyway try returning false on your OnClientClick and see if that helps.

Comment: The purpose of an ASP button is to submit an event to the code-behind. If you're trying to avoid that, then why not just use a regular `<input>`?

Comment: @TylerRoper Because I'm manipulating some things with it in the code behind

Comment: Unless you're using something like an UpdatePanel, you can't have it both ways. It either submits and fires an event on the code-behind, or you prevent the submit and the code-behind does not get hit. It sounds like you want a regular `<input>` tied to an AJAX call to the code-behind instead.

Comment: You could have a normal input with `runat="server` which allows you to manipulate it in the code-behind. e.g. `<input type="button" runat="server" id="LoginBtn"...`.

Comment: ^ This is correct. When OP said *"I'm manipulating some things with it in the code behind"* , I thought they meant "on click". However if they mean they're modifying the button itself from the code-behind, that is certainly an option.

Comment: the only thing that has worked (in the past, but no longer) has been to use the full <asp:button> control.

Comment: updated OP to reflect reverting source control to a working version.

Comment: So you do not want the postback to happen ?

Comment: @venu correct.  Everything should load so that when the initial login button is clicked it simply changes the client side CSS style to display the login form.  Inside the login form is a button that will submit to the server, validate login credentials, create a form authenticate session, and redirect the user to a different page.

Comment: This really seems like an XY problem. You have a problem and are set on a solution that may not be what you actually need. Mixing server side functionality and client side functionality can lead to really complicated, fragile systems. I would look for another solution.

Comment: @Marie I totally agree.  The whole website is the definition of a work in progress!  The whole intent is to try and improve my skills in web application development!  To that extent I'm slowly making things public on GitHub so I can look for suggestions on optimizing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="LoginBtn" type="Button" Text="Login" OnClientClick="javascript:document.getElementById('jsLogin').style.display='inline-grid'; return false;" />
```

Comment: If I can repro the original error, I'll attempt this solution.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the original error - updating OP

Comment: after cleaning up some code that was causing the root error, this solution fixed the problem of the button postback during the OnClientClick event.